# How to fix a value in a textbox?

Tags: html, textbox

I have a textbox to save the user facebook's url.

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        Facebook:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input style="width:300px" type="text" name="facebook" value="http://www.facebook.com/$facebook">
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can i make the value "http://www.facebook.com/" fixed and uneditable?

UPDATE:

the `$facebook` part needs to be editable!!

Comment: Check the latest edit to my answer: [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12878380/1190388) provided.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want that by default the `value` in the textbox will be `http://www.facebook.com/$facebook`? And then, what? Which part do you want to be editable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods to do this. One is to add the attribute `disabled="disabled"` to it, or add `readonly` to it.

Both work differently. What you need might be `disabled="disabled"` attribute.

## EDIT

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FaxE4/23/) updated. You should include following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inpt").val('http://www.facebook.com/$facebook');
    $("#inpt").on('change', function() {
        var tval = $(this).val();
        $(this).val('http://www.facebook.com/' + tval.substring(24));
    });
});
```

You may use keyboard events too, I am myself a beginner in jQuery, hence this basic piece of code. :) Also, update the `input` tag to this:

```
<input id="inpt" style="width:300px" type="text" name="facebook" value="Any VALUE YOU WANT">
```

Comment: In that case, you'd be needing JavaScript

Answer (score 4):

I think you are asking to have "http://www.facebook.com/" uneditable, but be able to edit the remainder of the url?

Something like the below snippet would be the simplest approach. Some tweaking of the styles as in the CSS below would make it more presentable.

```css
table {
    width: 500px;   
}
.fakey {
    border: solid 1px; 
    color: #ccc; 
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: .9em;    
}

.fakey input {
    border: none;   
    outline: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: .9em; 
    width: 200px;    
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Facebook:</td>
        <td>
            <div class="fakey">http://www.facebook.com/<input  type="text" name="facebook" value="$facebook" /></div>
        </td>
    </tr>        
</table>
```

Comment: i am using it that way, but its ugly. I want to show `http://www.facebook.com/` inside the text box.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript to force the prefix to remain entered at all cost.

```js
 $('input.facebookUrl').keyup(function(){
        if (
            ($(this).val().length > 0) && ($(this).val().substr(0,24) != 'http://www.facebook.com/')
            || ($(this).val() == '')
            ){
            $(this).val('http://www.facebook.com/');    
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
    <td>
        Facebook:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input style="width:300px" type="text" class="facebookUrl" name="facebook" value="http://www.facebook.com/$facebook">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Facebook:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input style="width:300px" disabled="disabled" type="text" name="facebook" value="http://www.facebook.com/$facebook" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: So then you should add some javascript to control this, CSS alone is not suffisant

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what your looking for but it is the best I could do.

```
 $("#input").keypress(function(ev){
      var value = "www.facebook.com/";
      var tval = this.value;
      var c = ev.charCode || ev.keyCode;
      this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
      if (tval.length == value.length && c == 8){
           ev.preventDefault();
      }
      this.value = value + tval.substring(value.length);
 });
```

Here's the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FaxE4/104/

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is to use the [`readonly` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) in the "input" HTML tag.

[`disabled`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp) is another property that can be usable.

References:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: If you use disabled attribute, when using a tool like a form filler, the value in the input field can be altered. Rather use readonly attribute on the input element and the value cannot be altered.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Facebook:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input style="width:300px" type="text" name="facebook" value="http://www.facebook.com/$facebook" readonly>
    </td>
</tr>
```